# Re-initiate Ionic modal once removed from DOM

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dom, ionic-framework

I am showing youtube videos in the modal, if I close the modal even then the videos will be playing in the background, so that's the issue.

I got a solution to remove modal from DOM and also I can add back again to DOM: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/remove-modal-from-dom/4676/8

With above given solution if there are more modals in the view then only first modal (for eg. Sign In Modal) that's in DOM gets added and removed in DOM. So, I need somebody to help me to provide me a solution where I can add as many modals but I need the modal to be removed and added back to the DOM.

Comment: Why don't you just stop the video programmatically when you close the modal? That's really what you're after right?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan, YouTube Video was just an example, the video will be served in any format HTM5 Video, iFrame, JS & HTML embedded videos etc... it's a ad platform. So what I need is to remove it completely from DOM and add back the same modal with different video.

Answer (score 0):

> A modal will broadcast ‘modal.shown’, ‘modal.hidden’, and ‘modal.removed’ events from its originating
>   scope, passing in itself as an event argument. Both the modal.removed and modal.hidden events are
>   called when the modal is removed.

so u can listen on the event, then empty content.